# Getting a file object of a directory

Tags: java, file

I need a File object pointing to a directory (may not be existing). How do I do that?

Even if I do something like

```
File dir = new File("/tmp/something/"); // with trailing slash
```

`dir.isDirectory()` is `false`. Then I tried `dir.mkdir()` which returns false, why? I dont need the directory to be existing, in fact, I want it to point to a directory that does not exist (I am doing testing). How can I achieve this?

Comment: You already have. `dir.isDirectory()` returned `false`, the folder does not exist. ;)

Comment: [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory()): "true if and only **if the file denoted by this abstract pathname exists** and is a directory; false otherwise"

Answer (score 1):

from javadoc: "true if and only if the file denoted by this abstract pathname exists and is a directory"

If the file does not exists isDirectory() return false. If you are doing testing probably use a stub can be a better option, in unit testing its better try to don't touch external resources like the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dir.mkdirs()`

`mkdirs()` will create the specified directory path in its entirety where `mkdir()` will only create the bottom most directory, failing if it can't find the parent directory of the directory it is trying to create.

Comment: Somehow it still returns false. The code evaluates to `new File("/tmp/nonexistant")`, I should be able to write to tmp, and create nonexistant whats wrong here?

Comment: Also I just want to get the File object without creating the directory, is it possible?

Comment: The File object require the path of the file,so directory is require but u can keep file in existing directory.No need to generate

Comment: "Also I just want to get the File object without creating the directory, is it possible?" I don't get it. You already have it because you're invoking isDirectory() on it. The directory creation might fail because the user used to run Java does not have the proper filesystem rights.

Answer (score 0):

Trailing slash does not matter.  File.isDirectory returns false because it returns true if and only if the file denoted by this abstract pathname exists and is a directory